# Access Fragment View from Activity's onCreate

Tags: android, fragment, oncreate, findviewbyid

I am in the process of making my first app for Android, and I have a `Fragment` that gets added to my `Activity` in the `Activity`'s `onCreate()` method. The problem I am facing is that I am unable to find any of the views contained within the `Fragment` from the `Activity`'s `onCreate()` method.

Other threads have suggested that this is because the `Fragment` has not yet been inflated, so `findViewById()` will return null for any views contained within the `Fragment`.

Here is what I mean:

Activity:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    System.out.println("activity onCreate");
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        return;
    }

    initialiseUI(); // Fragment added to Activity

    System.out.println("end of activity onCreate");
}
```

Fragment:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
System.out.println("fragment onCreateView");
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.event_log, container, false);
}
```

This prints the results:

activity onCreate
end of activity onCreate
fragment onCreateView

Because of this order, any attempt to access the views of the `Fragment` in the `Activity`'s `onCreate()` method (using `findViewById()`) produces a `NullPointerException`, as the `Fragment`'s `onCreateView()` only gets called AFTER the end of the `Activity`'s `onCreate()`.

Using the `FragmentManger`'s `executePendingTransactions()` after adding the `Fragment` doesn't help.

Basically, I have been forced to put the problem code in the `Activity`'s `onStart()` method instead of `onCreate()`, as `onStart()` happens AFTER the `Fragment`'s `onCreateView()`.

Does anyone what the standard practice here is, or how I can make my Fragment-View-accessing code work within the `Activity`'s `onCreate()` method?

Comment: Why do you want to access `Fragment`'s views in `Activity`'s `onCreate()` method? Something is wrong with your desing.

Comment: Specifically, after adding a Fragment in the Activity's onCreate() method, I want to change the text of a TextView contained within the Fragment, and add some items to a Spinner. What could be wrong with my design?

Comment: Than update your fragment's layout in `Fragment`'s `onCreateView()` method. See my answer.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Update your views in `onCreateView()`.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.event_log, container, false);
    TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text);
    tv.setText("hello world");
    return view;
}
```

Or if your changes depend on `Activity` your `Fragment` is attached to, use `onActivityCreated()`.

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    TextView tv = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.text);
    tv.setText(getActivity.getSomeText());
}
```

Comment: Ok, after a million other problems that I won't go into, I finally got this working properly! Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Dan, can you share exactly the other problems and how you used the above to solve it? It would be a great contribution ot the community.

Comment: Basically, I tried using onActivityCreated() to initialise my components, thinking this method would only be called once. This caused a lot of problems when pausing and restarting my app, as this method was resetting all of my components, since it gets called each time. Then, when trying to make this work using onCreateView(), I used getView().findViewById(...) rather than using the already-initialised "view" variable. It was a silly mistake, but I got there in the end! So now the text is stored to a field in onCreate(), and put into the TextView in onCreateView().

Comment: Please see my related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24833912/refresh-fragment-ui-from-fragmentactivity