# How to transfer variables to a fragment was created using the ActionBarActivity?

Tags: android-fragments

The activity is called from another activity delivering a string array, which needs to be displayed in a fragment of the target activity.

MainActivity (string array)  -> Result2Activity: Tab1 should display string index0, Tab2 should display string index1 etc.

I followed a similar problem here:

[Access Fragment View from Activity's onCreate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12122624/access-fragment-view-from-activitys-oncreate)

My problem is right now that the onActivityCreated method is never called in the Result2Activity.
I am also not sure if this method is the right way to address the fragment:

getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("Out1");

What is the best way to achieve that ?

**Result2Activity:**

```
public class Result2Activity extends ActionBarActivity implements
ActionBar.TabListener {

    /**
     * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
     * fragments for each of the sections. We use a {@link FragmentPagerAdapter}
     * derivative, which will keep every loaded fragment in memory. If this
     * becomes too memory intensive, it may be best to switch to a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
     */
    SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
     */
    ViewPager mViewPager;

    public List<String> fragments = new Vector<String>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.result2_activity);

        // Set up the action bar.
        final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the activity.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(
                getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        // When swiping between different sections, select the corresponding
        // tab. We can also use ActionBar.Tab#select() to do this if we have
        // a reference to the Tab.
        mViewPager
                .setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                        actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
                    }
                });

        // For each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.
        for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            // Create a tab with text corresponding to the page title defined by
            // the adapter. Also specify this Activity object, which implements
            // the TabListener interface, as the callback (listener) for when
            // this tab is selected.
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab()
                    .setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                    .setTabListener(this));
        }

        Log.d("DEBUG","1: onCreate finished");      
    }

    public void onActivityCreated (Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        Log.d("DEBUG","2: onActivityCreated finished");

        //super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        // retrieve data from MainActivity
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String message[] = intent.getStringArrayExtra(MainActivity.OUTPUT);

        //send data to fragment Out1Fragment
        Out1Fragment set_out1 = 
               (Out1Fragment) 
                 getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("Out1");
        set_out1.settext(message[0]);

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
        // When the given tab is selected, switch to the corresponding page in
        // the ViewPager.
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }

    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
            fragments.add(Out1Fragment.class.getName());
            fragments.add(Out2Fragment.class.getName());
            fragments.add(Out3Fragment.class.getName());

        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            Fragment fragment = null;
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                fragment = new Out1Fragment();
                break;
            case 1:
                fragment = new Out2Fragment();
                break;
            case 2:
                fragment = new Out3Fragment();
                break;
            }
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 3 total pages.
            return 3;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return getString(R.string.out_section1).toUpperCase(l);
            case 1:
                return getString(R.string.out_section2).toUpperCase(l);
            case 2:
                return getString(R.string.out_section3).toUpperCase(l);
            }
            return null;
        }

    }

}
```

**Out1Fragment:**

```
public class Out1Fragment extends Fragment {

    private static TextView textview;

    public Out1Fragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View dataView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.out1_fragment, container,
                false);

        textview = (TextView) dataView.findViewById(R.id.outPut1);

        return dataView;

    }

    public void settext(String text)
    {
        textview.setText(text);
    } 

}
```

**XML Resource:**

```
result2_activity.xml

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="dd.testing.finance.Result2Activity" />

out1_fragment.xml

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:tag="Out1" 
    tools:context="dd.testing.finance.Result2Activity$Out1Fragment" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/outPut1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10sp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10sp"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure if this was the right way, but at least it does exaclty what I needed.

In the Out1Fragment.class added the onActivityCreated method:

```
public void onActivityCreated (Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        settext(((Result2Activity)getActivity()).getOutput1());

}
```

From there calling the added method getOutput1 in the Result2Activity:

```
public String getOutput1 () {

    // retrieve data from MainActivity
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String message[] = intent.getStringArrayExtra(MainActivity.OUTPUT);
        return message[0];
}
```